# GridLayout and Dialog: How to align items correctly

Tags: java, dialog, swt, grid-layout

I would like to create a dialog in SWT. My code looks like this:

```
Shell dialog = new Shell(dialogShell, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM
            | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    dialog.setSize(800, 500);
    dialog.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 240);

    dialog.setText("Dummy dialog for stackoverflow");

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(4, false);

    dialog.setLayout(gridLayout);

    Button btnSave = new Button(dialog, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
    btnSave.setText("Save");
    btnSave.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, true, true, 1, 1));

    Button btnCancel = new Button(dialog, SWT.PUSH | SWT.CENTER);
    btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
    btnCancel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, true, true, 1,
            1));

    Tree tree = new Tree(dialog, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);

    GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL);
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 4;
    gridData.verticalSpan = 10;

    tree.setLayoutData(gridData);

    TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, 0);
    item.setText("Item 1");
    item = new TreeItem(item, 0);
    item.setText("Item 2");
    item = new TreeItem(item, 0);
    item.setText("Item 3");

    Label lblOne = new Label(dialog, SWT.NONE);
    lblOne.setText("Label One: ");

    Text textOne = new Text(dialog, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
    gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 3;
    textOne.setLayoutData(gridData);

    Label lblTwo = new Label(dialog, SWT.NONE);
    lblTwo.setText("Label Two: ");
    gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.verticalAlignment = SWT.TOP;
    lblTwo.setLayoutData(gridData);

    Text textTwo = new Text(dialog, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
    gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 3;
    textTwo.setLayoutData(gridData);

    dialog.pack();
    dialog.open();
```

The result looks like this:
[image: My SWT dialog]

I am not able to reach the following "goals":

- enlarge dialog in width so that the header text is completely readable
- enlarge the Tree so that it has at least eight rows in height
- set a minimum width for the Text controls so that they are not shrunk at the beginning when no data has yet been filled in

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `GridData` `heightHint` and `widthHint` values to specify the suggested height and width for the tree and text controls.

For example:

```
gridData.widthHeight = 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try and don't use `dialog.pack()` and instead give your elements arbitrary sizes in the begining. Then you can `pack()` it in some event handler, when you will see it fit. Also, I didn't do anything in SWT for a while, but have you tried `minimumWidth` properties?